# Delete last 8 characters out of string in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some output data from an ajax call and I would like to take out the last 8 characters of the data but also delete them out of that string that when I print out the data, the string I have taken would not show up.

Here is the code I have tried, It successfully takes that last 8 characters but does not remove them.

```
var data = "This is some data 12345678";
var comment_id = data.slice(-8);
jQuery.trim(comment_id);
$('#comments_'+comment_id).html(data);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var comment_id = data.slice(-8);
```

this line will not change the value of `data` it will only take out last 8 characters from the `data`. `data` is a string and it is immutable

add the following line after this line

```
data = data.substring(0, data.length -8);
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>**Why not substring?**</s>

```
var strLen=data.length,
comment_id=data.substring((strLen>=8?strLen-8:0),strLen);
```

(ignore this part of my answer)

**To remove them, do almost the same:**

`data=data.substring(0,strLen-8)`

Equivalent of:

`"daddaddad" to "d"`

(I didn't note you was wanting that, so I'm sorry)

Answer (score 1):

Return json from server side code

```
{message:"This is some data",comment_id:"12345678"}
```

You can access it like

```
$('#comments_'+data.comment_id).html(data.message);
```

Comment: I copied that code, I wrote alert(data.comment_id) and the output was "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice approach using regex that's a bit cleaner too:

```
var data = "This is some data 12345678",
    comment_id = data.match(/\d{8}$/)[0];
data = data.replace(comment_id, '').trim();
$('#comments_' + comment_id).html(data);
```

Comment: Regexp would be more heavy and equivalent to `substring`, but nah problem to do that.